# API Gateway: Unexpectedly high request count

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

I've recently enabled CloudWatch metrics for an API Gateway Stage and noticed unexpectedly high request count.

I'm observing it on my private account and so expect request count to be 0 with rare spikes when I manually test it. What I see it that the numbers are steady around 450 requests per 5 minutes intervals (1.5 rps):

[image]

The application itself is a serverless rest API and metrics of connected lambda show expected 0 invocations:

[image]

What could be the reason? is it some AWS service polling API Gateway?

Comment: So if your lambda is not invoked, then all these unexpected invocations end up in errors?

Comment: No, as API Gateway metrics for 4xx and 5xx show 0

Comment: The only thing I could think off, AWS related, would be maybe Route53 health checkers if you have custom domain set for your api.

Comment: That's right! I use DNS failover with configured health checks. Could you submit an answer, so I can approve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The API invokations were caused by [Route 53 health checkers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-determining-health-of-endpoints.html#dns-failover-determining-health-of-endpoints-monitor-endpoint) for custom domain. The domain is linked to the API.